# Facebook OAuth "An Error Has Occurred"

Tags: authentication, oauth, facebook-login, facebook-oauth

I'm having issues getting users logged in with my OAuth Dialog. This was working earlier today, so I suspect that it might be in conjunction with the [February Breaking Changes](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/). See for yourself in production at [WomStreet](http://womstreet.com).

Sandbox mode is disabled, the URL's are set properly in the basic setting section the developer page in facebook.

I am using devise for Ruby on Rails, but even inspecting the URL by hand seems to look good.

Any ideas on where to begin to debug?

**UPDATE 1:** Seems there is a bug report open on Facebook addressing this issue: [Link here](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/207955409343730?browse=search_5111d8fef19103526726758)

Comment: If you login to FB, you can subscribe to that bug to track it.

Answer (score 1):

looks like facebook got the dev community angry again by rolling out changes that effect the basic login.
i don't see any solution now but trying the login dialog here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/login/

bug link: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/207955409343730

**EDIT**:
to solv it you need to change your URL params. change:

```
app_id to: client_id
next to: redirect_uri
```

so the url you link to should look like:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=something&redirect_uri=something
```

Comment: The other topics on that page suggest server-side oauth is still available. Well, it does not say that server-side oauth is obsolete.

Comment: But isn't the change to dialog login mainly for apps? or is it also for websites?

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** Solved: I have been tinkering with this for the past 24 hrs, and I think I have the solution, which is at least two-fold:

1) Make sure you are using the correct url:

```
http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=[APP_ID]&redirect_uri=[YOUR_REDIRECT_URI]&state=[STATE]&scope=[SCOPE]
```

2) Log into facebook, go to developers.facebook.com, click your 'Apps' link at the very top center.  Go to each of the apps that is affected.  You may notice a red Alert on these apps. If you have alerts, they will instruct you that you need to enable February Breaking Changes before Feb 6th. Click 'Edit App.'  Go to Settings->Advanced on the left. Note that there are Enable/Disable inputs for upcoming Breaking changes, and note that February is no longer listed there.  Click Save Changes at the button, without actually changing anything - this action is evidently quietly Enabling Feb Braking Changes! Wait a few minutes for the changes to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

That same problem is there right now(the time I post this answer) on Stackoverflow facebook login as well. It might be the error from facebook side or as you said the changes have to made on the client side as mentioned in https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/

Comment: i have the same issue! what to do?

Comment: Post a support message to facebook which seems most suitable if they have also not mentioned about how to go on with the changes

Comment: Anyone find a solution yet?

Comment: None of the comments for the Feb 6 2013 changes are about Oauth. Seemingly. Opinions?

Comment: Yeah, it seems quite strange that this would break it. See update above for link on Facebook's page. Out of curiosity, is anyone using the Javascript API? I am not... I am linking directly to facebook.

Answer (score 0):

FB LOGIN was not working on stackoverflow but now it is working hence tapped the request response and found out that the URL used has been changed

the URl which we are using and is failing is 
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=

when we changed it to the following url which stackoverflow is using it started working..
property.facebook.authorize.url=https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=

hope this works for you all too.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Ruby and omniauth-facebook gem, you can try this forked one for now to use correct OAuth URL.

In Gemfile:

`gem 'omniauth-facebook', git: 'git://github.com/luvtechno/omniauth-facebook.git', branch: 'fix_oauth_url'`