# Facebook GraphAPI 'An error occured. Please try again later"

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth

I've been getting this error since around 7:15 ish, everything was working fine before.
I went to check on the 'health status' and noticed the following.

Push: Complete
As of today at 7:25pm

Coincidence?

My site URL is IP based and I've made several Apps in the facebook developer's portal using the same IP while testing out permission settings.

Is anyone else having an issue? Would having multiple apps with the same site URL cause my IP to be banned?

Comment: duplication: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14721279/facebook-oauth-an-error-has-occurred

Comment: Solved : 
you can check this link.it solved my issue

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14722725/enabling-facebook-breaking-changes-feb-2013-login-does-not-work

Answer (score 0):

There's a problem on a variety of sites supporting oauth, check out a similar post [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14721279/facebook-oauth-an-error-has-occurred) and the corresponding [facebook thread](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/207955409343730?browse=search_5111d8fef19103526726758)