# Enabling Facebook Breaking Changes Feb 2013: login Does Not Work

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, cordova, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working on phonegap with ios and using facebook login.
but on feb 6, its giving errors to users while login to facebook.

When logging into the app using Facebook - the dialog shows this message: "An error occurred. Please try again later.

I go through fb manual and enable migration in "February 2013 Breaking Changes".
it still not worked.

Can any one help me ?

**Edited :**

I reffer to facebook DOC and found this

**"The following change will go into effect on February 6th, 2013:
End of custom actions for content consumption
We will no longer show Custom Open Graph actions that were published simply by a user consuming content. If you own one of these actions and it was previously approved, you will have received an email from us. Developers should stop publishing these actions as doing so will return an error starting February 6th. The only actions that can be published upon a user simply consuming content are built-in actions. For more info, see this blog post."**

the solution given over there is to make migration oprion from "disabled" to "enabled" which i do,even they give me confirmation that problem resolved but problem is still on.

**Working :**
Its little surprising but now both of my links working well as describe below in answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved:

i am able to login now,there is little change in facebook doc for using graph api.
my issue solved by just replacing url from.

**"https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=404196699634359&redirect_uri=http://www.facebook.com...."**

to

**"http://facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=404196699634359&redirect_uri=http://www.facebook.com..."**

And finally my app workes as before.
special thanks to this
http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/207955409343730?browse=search_5111f1ed718835f53574450

Answer (score 0):

For people like me who know just enough to be dangerous and nothing more... I have no idea where this oauth URL lives and where to change it.  Is this a facebook App settings?  Is it a change in the src fodler?  I can't find this link anywhere in my code to make the correction.

Comment: @webmaster: please provide me more information how you connecting to facebook? i am using JavaScript api and you have to provide this link when you try to login through facebook and username and password (loginpage) of facebook opens just for authorized login. i can't give you my link for security purpose.