# Facebook Graph API in iPhone Not working after Feb 6 Changes

Tags: iphone, facebook, facebook-graph-api, ios6

**I got alert & mail from facebook as following:**

February 2013 Breaking Changes
Sunday
Your app, , needs to be updated for the February 2013 Breaking Changes.
Once your app is compliant, set the migration setting to "Enabled" in the Advanced section of the App Dashboard.

I have also ENABLED migration setting , but still getting error. I have also attached screenshots of both error and alert here.

Please help if any have solved this issue.

[image]

Comment: they r working on it at the moment and it is currently working , please check the facebook developers page ...

Comment: Facing same problem in my application also.....

Comment: @Gill-TheIronMan yes. i read that. but i want to know that can we get accesstoken if we use graphapi?. i didnt get that.because when we click okay. it redirect to login page and then when login it open the default facebook web. so how we get token. and the another question is there any problem with posting with old token if we post using old token.

Comment: @ChinttuRoxeNRamani go to http://developers.facebook.com/ , then click on APPs tab at the top , there you can edit or create an app , after which they provide u with a unique Id ....

Comment: @Gill-TheIronMan i already created app and edit that february migration settings that facebook sent mail to me. i was just confirm that it will create problem or not.

Comment: Your question is extremely unclear as to what isn't working and how you're getting to that error, i'd strongly consider clarifying if you want people to help

Comment: Check this link please
It solved my issue

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14722725/enabling-facebook-breaking-changes-feb-2013-login-does-not-work

Answer (score 0):

Did you manage to resolve your issue?
I searched for a while on this and found a very simple solution:

- Go to your app settings and select the advanced tab.
- Change the 'App type' to web

That's it, it got my apps working, hope it helps.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Change the facebook Url from this url..

> https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=404196699634359&redirect_uri=http://www.facebook.com....

to

> http://facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=404196699634359&redirect_uri=http://www.facebook.com...