# Facebook breaking changes Feb | Authenticated referrals going away

Tags: facebook-login, facebook-oauth, facebook-authentication

I have developed a Facebook game, and it requires authentication when a player loads the game. Previously it was working fine. Whenever a "new" user try to play my game, he needs to click on "allow" button to give the permissions. This dialog was working fine previously but now Facebook is going to apply some changes, known as Feb 2013 breaking changes.

When I "Enable" the February 2013 breaking changes through Facebook setting of my app, my application didn't work for existing and new users. In fact the "allow" permission dialog is not loading.

Previously I was successfully using the following method for authentication, which is not working now when I enabled the Feb 2013 breaking changes via game setting. 
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth? (link1)

Now I also tried to use another method for authentication
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize? (link 2)

but it didn't work either. The application is not redirected to app canvas page. In fact I got an error code 307 twice, and then it redirects the page to (link 1)
which is not working.

Could you please help me what is happening, and how could I make my authentication work?

Comment: Note: I'm using Python.

Comment: Check this please
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14722725/enabling-facebook-breaking-changes-feb-2013-login-does-not-work
it solved my issue

Answer (score 0):

Authenticated referrals are gone, so you need to think of an alternative way to ask your users for permissions. You can use the javascript SDK for that. You need to load the SDK first:

```
(function(d){
    var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
    js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
    ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
}(document));
```

Then you need to init your application:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function()
{
    FB.init({
        appId:'YOUR_APP_ID',
        status:true,
        cookie:true,
        xfbml:true
    });
};
```

Finally you have to create a login function, that will handle your custom logics:

```
function login()
{
    FB.login(function(response){
        if(response.authResponse)
        {
            //CUSTOM CODE GOES HERE
        }
    },{scope:'publish_actions'});
}
```