# February breaking changes - my action link stopped working

Tags: facebook-graph-api, custom-action, actionlink

My application allows two actions: ask and give recommendations. I have got approval for both the actions. Clearly both these actions are non-content consuming (based on the Facebook definition in their guidelines). The feed for 'ask action' has an action link for 'give action'. After I enabled February breaking change the action link  stopped working. How can I get that enabled again?

Comment: That sounds like a bug, and possibly a bug unrelated to the migration, you should probably file a bug report with facebook

Comment: Thanks, the link was working for admins and developers before I enabled the February breaking changes. Now it stopped working for those users also. So I assume it is related.

Comment: Check this link please
it solved my issue

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14722725/enabling-facebook-breaking-changes-feb-2013-login-does-not-work

Comment: Thanks Raj, I don't have any issue with FB login. My issue was specifically with action link (custom action).